# Is it possible to store files on Ubuntu One without syncing them to a (or every) computer?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I would like to use Ubuntu One on all of my computers, but I don't want all of the files to be synced with every computer.  Some of my computers don't have a big enough hard drive to sync everything.  I would like to have access to the files in the cloud, without having everything stored on my hard drive.  Is this a current or planned feature?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's possible.

While files that are placed in the main Ubuntu One folder (`~/Ubuntu One/`) will currently get synced to all your Ubuntu One enabled computers, you do control which additional folders get synced. Although this functionality isn't currently exposed in a user-friendly way, you can still use it via `u1sdtool`: you can subscribe (and unsubscribe) to folders using `u1sdtool --subscribe=<folder id>` (and, respectively, `--unsubscribe=<folder id>`); you can get the `folder id` from `u1sdtool --list-folders`.

When on one computer you select “synchronize this folder with Ubuntu One” in nautilus (or `u1sdtool --create-folder=/path/to/folder`), your other computers do a “folder merge” and start syncing that folder too, *if the value of `udf_autosubscribe` in `/etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` is set to True*.

So, on the computer with a smaller hard drive, edit that file and set the value of `udf_autosubscribe` to `False`. You can then manually add the folders you want to be included using `u1sdtool`. With this you have access to some of your files immediately, and you can fall back to the web interface for the rest.

This is not the same as having something like a webdav mount, but it probably covers your needs.

Comment: We're working on making this feature user friendly for Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty). You'll be able to select which (if any) folders you want to sync on each of your computers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in the latest versions to disable what folders are synced to a particular computer by unchecking them in the folders tab. Note that they will still be stored on the cloud for all other computers.

This won't automatically unsubscribe after so much being downloaded, but you have more control over what is selected, and it's a halibut easier.

Further, there is an option to not subscribe automatically to new folders. Try that, too.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a current feature maybe it would be a planned one. for the above purpose you can use a file sharing site or maybe you can choose to use a cloud os . you can use jolicloud which is good

Answer (score 0):

I have to note that we have a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/682878 which causes the files to continue being downloaded from unsubscribed folders so this --unsubscribe feature is not that useful now.

Comment: This bug has been fixed.